# Saving the value for a taxonomy term field

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to save a field value for a taxonomy term, my value appears in the term array, but the "fields" array is empty. I'm not sure if it's right what I am going to do. You can see everything about my case in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I don't see what's wrong, everything looks ok. Maybe explain why do you need not empty fields array? I think it is not empty only when you make changes to entity. Hope someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Trupal said, forget about the internal properties of the term objects, that's internal details that are not relevant to you.

If you want to see what's inside, try $term->toArray() and look at the result of that in your debugger. Or access the field value with $term->field_foo->value.